# Create community module

Tags: module, configuration, magento-1, magento-community, composer

I downloaded megento with composer and installed it,ther `app/code` directory for creating module, So i just created this directory and my module directory like this :

[image]

And `etc\modules` as the same,i created it. But the module its not in Magento module list.
The `app/code/community/Shareino/SyncModule/etc/config` file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shareino_SyncModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Shareino_SyncModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The `app/etc/modules/Shareino_SyncModule` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shareino_SyncModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Shareino_SyncModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

But this module isnot in magento's module list.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems here.

First you need a module folder, here you only have a `Shareino` folder which acts as a Vendor/Namespace folder but no module folder.

So create `app/code/community/Shareino/SyncModule`

Then move your `etc` folder in that folder.

You need at least a `config.xml` under your `app/code/community/Shareino/SyncModule/etc` folder which has at least the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shareino_SyncModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Shareino_SyncModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Finally your `app/etc/module/Shareino_SyncModule.xml` must look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shareino_SyncModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Shareino_SyncModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi, i did all of your instructions but it doesn't com to module list.